# Reading digit values from excel sheet

Tags: c#

In my excel sheet i have one column contain digits.
Like:

```
  500

  10,973.14

  12,456.23
```

when i read i got values
like:

500

10,973.141

12,456.2345

Let me know how to read values what ever appearing in excel sheet.

Output :

500

10,973.14

12,456.23

i used oledbconnect. code like ;`

```
              for (i = 0; i < accountcopytab.Rows.Count-2; i++)
                  {
                       currentRow = accountcopytab.Rows[i];
                       if (currentRow["Credit"].ToString().Length > 0)
                      {    
                          Creditvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow["Credit"]);
                           -------------
                           --------------``
                      }
                }
```

Comment: what you are using for reading from excel file ?

Comment: i am using oledb  OleDbConnection.Code:                                                              for (i = 0; i < accountcopytab.Rows.Count-2; i++)
                    {
                        currentRow = accountcopytab.Rows[i];

                        if (currentRow["Credit"].ToString().Length > 0)
                             Creditvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow["Credit"]);
                              -------------
                               --------------

Comment: please update your question, code in comments is very hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the actual value in Excel is 12,456.2345 and Excel is truncating/rounding?  In other words, your program is reading and display what's actually in Excel.

If that's the case and you want to truncate the C# output, you can use this pattern: `"#,#.##"`

Comment: if i use that pattern it is read only upto two digits.But i have to read the data excel sheet what ever it contain(digits).It is not consider how many digits are there.it has to read all the digits.

Comment: @KaivthaBindela: The pattern in my answer is for output formatting.  For example, MyNumber.ToString("#,#.##").  After reading your comment to my answer and your comment to your original question, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to ask.  If you simply want to read in everything in the Excel document, there isn't much you need to do.  If you want to read in EXACTLY what Excel is displaying (even if Excel is truncating your number due to space issues), then there isn't much you can do.